# string-to-number and insert give control characters (e.g., ^C, ^D) instead of numbers (e.g., 3, 4)

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

I am trying to make a function that prompt the user to enter a number during a `while` (so the number of time the prompt appears will change, that is why I don't want to use something like `(interactive "n Enter a Number : ")`).  My code is like this:

```
 (setq nb_str (read-string "Enter a Number:"))
 (setq nb (string-to-number nb_str))
 (insert nb)
```

When I want to insert the variable `nb`, instead of having my number inserted, I get some weird output from `string-to-number` function like `^C` (if I typed 3) or `^D` (if I typed 4) or `^E` (if I typed 5).  I need that value as number for after. How can I do this?

Comment: why not just use `read-number` if you want a number?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`insert`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Insertion.html) inserts strings or characters, and a number in Emacs Lisp *is* a character (if it is in the right range), so 3 is inserted as the 3rd ASCII char, `^C`.

You need to either pass `nb-str` to `insert`, or use [`number-to-string`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/String-Conversion.html):

```
(insert (number-to-string nb))
```

Comment: A nit: *Some* numbers are characters.  Characters are numbers, but not necessarily vice versa.